# Will this rational parametric solution generate all possible solutions?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I was looking for integer solutions to this equation: 
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=d^3$$
And found a parametric solution. Given u, v, w :
\begin{cases}
a=3\left(u^2v+v^2w+w^2u\right)\\
b=3\left(uv^2+vw^2+wu^2\right)\\
c=u^3+v^3+w^3+6uvw\\
d=u^3+v^3+w^3-3uvw
\end{cases}

A Natural Extension of the Pythagorean 
Equation to Higher Dimensions
http://www.math.grinnell.edu/~chamberl/papers/pythagorean.pdf

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049581___    https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1046862___

Answer (score 1):

Above equation shown below:

$\begin{cases}
a=3\left(u^2v+v^2w+w^2u\right)\\
b=3\left(uv^2+vw^2+wu^2\right)\\
c=u^3+v^3+w^3+6uvw\\
d=u^3+v^3+w^3-3uvw
\end{cases}$

$(a,b,c,d)=(2,4,3,3)$

Above value's is not a solution for the equation (given in bracket).

Since the equation submitted by "OP" does not generate all possible

solutions the answer to his question is negative.